# How to get whole output of php system function

Tags: php, linux

I want to get all the router list of my network using php on linux.
I have tried php exec and system function but it is give only one router in output.

How to get whole list of router?

```
$last_line = system('iwlist scan', $retval);
echo '
</pre>
<hr />Last line of the output: ' . $last_line . '
<hr />Return value: ' . $retval;

$last_line = system('iwlist scan | grep ESSID', $retval);

echo '

<hr />Last line of the output: ' . $last_line . '
<hr />Return value: ' . $retval;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use passthru to retrieve all of the output.

You must understand that there are different output streams to consider here:

- `iwlist` will probably produce text on [stdout](/questions/tagged/stdout) and [stderr](/questions/tagged/stderr) (due to other interfaces that don't support wireless)
- `grep` will only receive the output through the pipe from [stdout](/questions/tagged/stdout)
- `passthru` will receive both [stdout](/questions/tagged/stdout) and [stderr](/questions/tagged/stderr) from `iwlist` and `grep`.

You can redirect the output so that you only get the successful output that has been grep'ed.  The whole thing then becomes:

`echo passthru('iwlist scan 2>/dev/null | grep ESSID');`

Comment: Thanks @paul It give all the router list first when I have refresh page it is lost router list and display first router.Plz tell me what's the problem? Any changes require in my code?

Comment: iwlist is a privileged operation, running it as a non root user may return only the networks that it is aware of (or the previous scan result which is what you probably saw at first).

Comment: It is possible to store all the router list in text file may be cause of echo function it's return first router. Any idea about this.

Comment: no, as I said, the reason why it would only be showing one user is because you aren't running as root.  Check it from the command line as root / non-root users, you will see that I am correct.  Use: `php -r "echo passthru('iwlist scan 2>/dev/null | grep ESSID');"`  You will see that root gets the full list, non-root only gets the full list for a short amount of time (until your wireless device does another scan - the wireless device will do this from time to time outside of your control).

Comment: You can force the full list to appear again by performing the command again as root which will refresh the saved list of routers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) instead of `system`. The second parameter for `exec()` is an (optional) array. Each line of output that your command returns will be in that array.

```
$output = array();
exec('iwlist scan', $output, $retval);
print_r($output);
```

Comment: Thanks but it's write first router description in output array.I want to get list of router, any idea?

Comment: Are you sure `iwlist scan` produces the desired output?

Comment: Ya I have tested this command on linux command prompt and it's give list of all the routers.